# CSS or Javascript DIV align

Tags: javascript, css

I have website that where the php code generates all the products on the same page.

So far i get something like this.

http://ratecleveland.com/irregular_height_columns.jpg

however i am trying to get something like this.

http://ratecleveland.com/new.jpg

any idea if this can be done in css. or if no, is there a javascript examle.

thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle, use display:inline-block; with the ?display hack

http://jsfiddle.net/qW3TV/

No javascript is necessary.

Comment: this is my backup the jquery is great but i will also use this for non java devices. thank you

Comment: @user1170117 java is an unacceptable abbreviation for javascript

Comment: only javascript and js are correct, never java or jscript, they mean different things

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all of the divs are the same width. Why not just create containing column divs around the ones you want to stack?

```
<div class="col1">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="e"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="k"></div>
</div>
<div class="col3">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="g"></div>
    <div class="l"></div>
</div>
<div class="col4">
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="h"></div>
    <div class="m"></div>
</div>
```

Float each column left and your interior div's, which appear to already have specified width and height, will fall into place. You can even give the columns the same class, since they will just be floated left containers.